# An IOS Application project must reference the project containing this xaml file in order to render in the previewer

Tags: xamarin.forms

In Previewer below error is shown `An IOS Application project must reference the project containing this xaml file in order to render in the previewer.`

PCL reference is added in IOS project and Xamarin.forms latest nuget package is also added .

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple. This works for me in android project. The error message is self explanatory. Solution: Check your android project and make sure the dll of your PCL/.net standard project is reference. In my own case, its referenced but shows a yellow color. I deleted the reference and re-reference by right clicking on the android project=>projects=>solution=>select the PCL/.net standard project => ok ..

[image]